Is there a notion of mean value theorem (MVT) for a $C^1$ curve on Banach space?
Let $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow E$ be a $C^1$ curve, in the sense that the Frechet derivative exists and is continuous on $[a,b]$:
$$ \forall t \in [a,b],\quad \dot \gamma(t) = \lim_{s\rightarrow t} \frac{\gamma(s) -\gamma(t)}{s-t} \ \text{exists}.$$
I wonder if there is a version of mean value theorem in this case?
The following example shows that we can not have a naive generalization like in real analysis:
$$ \gamma(t) = (\cos t,\sin t), \quad t \in [0,2\pi],$$
then there is no $z \in [0,2\pi]$ such that
$$ \dot \gamma(z) = \frac{\gamma(2\pi) - \gamma(0)}{2\pi} = 0$$
since $ \| \dot \gamma(t)\| = 1, \forall t \in [0,2\pi]$.
Appreciate any references!

The inequality version of MVT holds for functions with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions. It is not hard to generalize this to functions with values in a Banach space.
